# Stop cloth from gliding of

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

I am trying to make a ghostlike animation. Cloth floating over a simple armature. This all works very well, right until the point I want the ghost to move it's arms. In theory the cloth over him should move with him, in practice it glides of.

How can I stop it from gliding of? So far, I've tried pinning and hooking. But that doesn't work, seems to horribly distort the cloth. Also, I can't start the cloth hooked, as it has to fall down first. I am really at a loss here. The animation included shows what's happening better then I can describe.

https://youtu.be/-x4r8ZSitVM

Blender file added for clarification. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gtmegd3wjukylkj/Shared.blend?dl=0

Comment: Please upload your .blend file to be able to help you

Comment: what order are your modifier in? you need the cloth sim after the armature.

Comment: I've added the blender file.
When I tried the hook thing, I had hook before cloth in the order.

Answer (score 2):

Try turning up the friction in the [Cloth Collision settings.](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/cloth/settings/collisions.html)

[image]